# jquery-ui menu does not position as expected

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to RTLize jquery-ui menu. i'e i want to make sub-menus drop at left side of their parents.

I've used positioning for this, but it only works for level 2, and other levels dropped in right side of their parents instead of at left side

JSBIN :http://jsbin.com/uDaZezIX/1/edit?html,output

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the position the wrong way. Change to:

```
[...].menu({position:{ my: "right top", at: "left top"}});
```

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu